# jQuery Masonry appending items with 'load more' ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml-parsing, jquery-masonry

My objective = retrieve a list of items via ajax, display n slides on page load, then append n items with each click of 'load items' until all items are displayed at which point display something like 'no more left' etc.

I've got the ajax call and append items working independently, but need help to make them work together.

Here is my ajax call, which I've placed inside a function called populateBlocks:

```
function populateBlocks(position,page_size) {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/portfolio.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      var title, url, block_count;
      block_count = $(xml).find('block').length;
      $(xml).find('block').slice(position,position+page_size).each(function(){
         title = $(this).find('title').text();
         url = $(this).find('url').text();
         $('div.section').append('<div class="item"><a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + url + '" alt="" /><span class="title"><span class="text">' + title + '</span></span></a></div>');
      });
      $('.section').masonry('reload');
    }
    });      
}
```

And here's what's loaded on document ready, including the handler for the 'load items' click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var position;
var page_size;

populateBlocks(0,9);

  $('#append2').click(function(position){
    $boxes = populateBlocks(9,9);
    $('#container').append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes );
  });
});
```

I'm aware the code is probably all kinds of wrong. I was experimenting with using function parameters and also incrementing the position and page_size variables after clicking but couldn't get any joy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line:

```
$('#container').append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes );
```

with this:

```
jQuery("#content").append($boxes).masonry( 'reload' );
```

Comment: thanks kleinohad but that line is works ok either way. What I'm after is a way to pass the 'slice' parameters to the populateBlocks function